# Print HTML with PHP within function without echo

Tags: php

I've no clue if what I want is possible so a "no is not possible" could also be an answer for me.

Im making a PHP function like this:

```
<?php
function set_block_title($post){
    echo "<p class='title'>$post->get_title()</p>";
}
```

I would like to do this without an echo and instead get the html out of the PHP page (mainly because the designers who will break all the PHP when they don't have the HTML syntax).

I know it's possible with an if statement like this:

```
<?php if( condition ): ?>
    <p class='title'>
        <?php echo $post->get_title(); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with a PHP function? I suppose I could do something like this:

```
<?php
function set_block_title($post){
    <?php if( true ): ?>
        <p class='title'>
            <?php echo $post->get_title(); ?>
        </p>
    <?php endif;
}?>
```

Comment: instead of `echo` just `return` the statement. But am not clear with what your need actually is

Comment: Oops, sorry, will try to avoid it in the future.

Comment: @StefanJanssen You could try to use one of the many view frameworks currently available that blend into the markup....

Answer (score 2):

There is another way of printing a php variable in your html:
instead of using:

> "php echo $variable;"

you can use:

> php =$variable;"

Comment: That is only possible with a certain setting of PHP, and I also have more things to echo within the function :P

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:
Steps required BEFORE doing this are -- 1) A template file, preferably with the extension of PHP. 2) Basic knowledge of PHP. -- This is the fastest way.

```
$tmplt = readfile("PageTemplate.php");
echo $tmplt;
```

I hope I helped! Read up on the Readfile function at [PHP.net - Readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)
-- By the way: I know you asked for no echo, but you also asked to see the html syntax, so despite this having echo, it will still have the marks and everything. Sorry!

Comment: It has been quite some time since I asked this question, I don't know why I asked this and how I solved it in the end, so I gave you a vote up but I can't really give an "Correct answer", sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way also.

```
<?php
function set_block_title($post){
   $html = "<p class='title'>$post->get_title()</p>";
  return $html;
}
?>
```

try above code may helps you.

Comment: hmm the main reason why I wanted to remove the echo is to get HTML syntax highlighting and seperating PHP and HTML. So this is not what I'm looking for.